# Pushwoosh TTL for different browsers

Tags: browser, push-notification, ttl, pushwoosh

I Am using Pushwoosh, on createMessage() api call, I am able to specify the message's TTL parameter. I am currently testing in Chrome and Firefox.

In the createMessage() call, I am specifying `'chrome_gcm_ttl' => 300,` which means that the message will live for 5 minutes.
(I am assuming that Firefox and Chrome both use this value as they both use GCM/FCM)

I have tested this in chrome. (closed the browser, sent the message, wait 4min30s, I am able to receive the push) - Working as intended

However, in FireFox, I have tested on multiple occasions, And messages are never received after the 1 minute mark after numerous attempts. (But are able to get messages below the 1 minute mark)

Is this intended behaviour? Why is the TTL ignored in FireFox ? Where is the TTL for firefox set as 60 seconds? Is there another way to override this value? Or is it stuck at 60 seconds no mater what? Firefox browser is 52.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed by default Firefox push TTL is set to 60 by Pushwoosh, so yes, it is an intended behavior and currently it is out of user's control.

I suppose the best idea is to contact Pushwoosh team and submit a feature request via [this form](http://pushwoosh.com/contact-us) or at their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/web-push-notifications).